# Flash player with Red5 server codec type detection

Tags: flash, audio, red5, rtmp, codec

I use Red5 server 0.9.1 for live streaming from Adobe Flash player to my RTMP protocol transport.

I test it with audio data captured from my microphone using flash application and for now transport recieves and recognizes audio packets. For further audio data listening I need to know what audio codec Flash player uses to send data to the Red5 server.

Transport doesn't recieve any metadata packets with detailed information about media codec. All I know for now from "connect" message is that publishing side supports the set of audio and video codecs.

Please, give any suggestions about this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some steps the answer is found:

- Red5 have functionality to save live stream into file (flv container).
- In flash application we use publish("Name", "record");
- Red5 creates file Name.flv wich contains audio data.
- Using VLC player I play this file and get detailed info (VLC uses Ffmpeg for this purpose, so it is possible to get info using Ffmpeg)

And the answer is "NellyMoser ASAO" mono audio codec.
The same info I found in the Red5 server sources.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the audio codec configurable? I think along with NellyMoser, Speex is supported as well.

Answer (score 0):

The default codec for audio in a browser using Flash Player is NellyMoser ASAO, but you can select the codec in AS3 in later versions of the player. While Nelly is fine for most purposes, you can also use Speex and G.711 as well.

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplatformruntimes/flashplayer11/